# How to bind visual description to repository fields

Tags: c#, uwp

I need to store properties to display repository field in view. Properties like number of columns where the field will be displayed, sorting order, name of field and description will be displayed on view ...

Those properties have to be stored for every field i.e. Id, authorname, ... in this example:

```
public class IEntity
{
    public string Id; 
}

public partial class Author : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string authorname { get; set; }
}
```

Sample of properties to store for every field

```
 public enum SortedProperty    // State of sorting database Field
 {
    Unsorted, Ascent, Descent
 }

 public String resourceName { get; set; }         // Name of field
 public String resourceDescription { get; set; }  // Description of field
 public String formatString { get; set; }         // String defining display of field 
 public long columnOrder { get; set; }            // Order of column where field be displayed
 public SortedProperty sortProperty { get; set; }   // State of sorting field
 public long sortOrder { get; set; }                // Order of sorting
```

I need to store visual design of table in database for later use. Those properties will be used next time table will be open to respect last user modification of View.

Please give some advice how design code to make bind between field and display properties.

Comment: Why not put the data in a `DataTable` and use its columns' properties (e.g. `ColumnName` or [`Caption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.caption?view=netframework-4.8)) to store your metadata? Any custom metadata could go in the [ExtendedProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.extendedproperties?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Thank you for those words. It helps me to use proper way. @JohnWu